# ImageMagick: Error while running convert: convert: unable to read font

Tags: imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion

I'm on Mountain Lion and installed ImageMagick using Homebrew (minimagick is also in my Gemfile but I don't think that's relevant). [SimpleCaptcha](https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha) uses it in a Rails app to create CAPTCHAs.

However, the image isn't created cause of this error:

```
Error while running convert: convert: unable to read font `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n019003l.pfb' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1123.
convert: Postscript delegate failed `/var/folders/gd/n7rzfhkd5jd0ws8jnzsz34hr0000gn/T/magick-vzHHz4ZP': No such file or directory @ error/ps.c/ReadPSImage/830.
convert: no images defined `/var/folders/gd/n7rzfhkd5jd0ws8jnzsz34hr0000gn/T/simple_captcha20121218-64930-1thtfpf.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3032.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Looks like you're missing [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/). If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you can install it via:

```
$ brew install ghostscript
```

Comment: Sometimes you have ghostscript but it's just not linked!

`$ brew unlink ghostscript && brew link ghostscript`

Comment: This also works when the error message doesn't specifiy the missing font, as in `convert: unable to read font \`(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1153`

Comment: is there anyone for windows help?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu or in a  docker with Ubuntu  remove and reinstall ghostscript package will fix your issue

`apt remove ghostscript` 
`apt install ghostscript`

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, `fc-list --format "%{fullname[0]}\n"` was being used to obtain font names which did not agree with the output from `convert -list font`. But, `convert -font` will accept a full path instead of a font name (can be obtained from `fc-list --format "%{file[0]}\n"`) which avoids name matching and location resolution issues.

This situation has been repaired in [fontviewer](https://github.com/PaulCarmanPro/fontviewer/tree/main).

Note: `fc-list` locates more fonts than `convert -list font`.