# Rmagick unable to read font

Tags: ruby, fonts, imagemagick, rmagick

I have a piece of code that draws text on top of an image in my Rails app and since short while ago, probably having to to with upgrading to OS X Yosemite, it's having an issue with reading fonts on my local machine (production server is working fine).

I can reduce it to this example:

```
require 'rvg/rvg'
font = '"/Users/xxxxxxxx/xxxx/app/assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf"'
rvg = Magick::RVG.new(100,100) do |canvas|
  canvas.text(0, 0, 'my text').styles(font: font)  
end  
rvg.draw
```

I get this error

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to read font `"/Users/xxxxxxxx/xxxx/app/assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf"' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1153: `(null)'
from /Users/xxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@xxxxxxxx/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rvg/misc.rb:322:in `get_type_metrics'
```

I tried reinstalling imagemagick and the rmagick gem, also with these flags:

```
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
```

Also, if I change

```
font = "/Users/xxxxxx/xxxxx/app/assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf"
```

thinking that the extra quotes could get in the way, then I get

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `Users/xxxxx/xxxx/app/assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3170
from /Users/xxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@xxxx/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rvg/misc.rb:546:in `draw'
```

I have also tried to install the latest version of XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Comment: Would you mind to try `font = 'url(/Users/xxxxxx/xxxxx/app/assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf)'`? Single quotes for the whole string, no quotes more. On my Ubuntu the dependence on quotes type is even more weird.

Comment: Thanks but the issue was something completely different. I added an answer

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Strangely enough, this fixed it:

```
brew install gs
```

The error got me confused because it didn't say anything about ghostscript, however, it worked according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936374/322253

Comment: Awesome! Installing gs fixed the issue for me!!