# Github action raises "convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono'" error and similar

Tags: fonts, github-actions

I am trying to perform some Github action tests as part of a CI workflow. These tests should do quite a bit of pdf / png actions, but I am hitting issues with `` convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono' ``. I have tried to fix these by installing / reinstalling `ghostscript` before the tests following some advices online, with no success. Basically the Github action looks like:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: quick tests
        run: |
          cd src
          bash install.sh
          cd ../tests/
          bash run_all_tests.sh
```

Where the tests fail with the following output:

```
convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/915.
convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1338.
convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4300.
convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/915.
convert-im6.q16: unable to read font `FreeMono' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1338.
convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4300.
```

This works on my personal Ubuntu 20.04 machine, and I do not think that I have ever needed to tweak ghostscript or convert-im6 (at least nothing that I remember).

Any idea how to fix these issues so that it works on the Github action latest ubuntu in the same way as on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer... The SO issues I had found (for example [ImageMagick: Error while running convert: convert: unable to read font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936256/imagemagick-error-while-running-convert-convert-unable-to-read-font) , [ImageMagickError unable to read font `(null)': `(null)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014506/imagemagickerror-unable-to-read-font-null-null) , and the likes) only mentioned that I needed to install `ghostscript`, `gs` or related, but in my case I needed both `ghostscript` and also to install the fonts separately. So adding a separate step:

```
     - name: install ghostscript and its fonts
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install ghostscript
          sudo apt-get install fonts-freefont-otf
```

solved my problem. Not sure why I never had this kind of issues on my Ubuntu laptop, guess some configuration differences with the `ubuntu-latest` provided by github actions (?).